# LyX. How to change space between paragraph and list

Tags: lyx

How to change space between paragraph and list?
I'm new in Lyx.
Can I do it without code?
[image]

Comment: Welcome, what buttons did you click to get this result? You should have a bit of LaTeX experience to deal with LyX. That way you would not be scared by harmless pieces of code :-/

Comment: I insert text with default layout. Then I insert some lines and press ALT+P E. I tried to insert in preamble `\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` . It did not effect

Comment: hmm. I had `\begin_layout Enumerate
\paragraph_spacing single
\noindent
IP-адрес устройства.
\end_layout`. I deleted `\paragraph_spacing single
\noindent` Space decreased

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов Can you post minimal example .lyx (and corresponding .tex) files? Please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample